# Uncaught ReferenceError: Navbar is not defined

Tags: reactjs, meteor

I develop react + meteor app, then I got error like this,

[image]

I try to add navigation https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components.html#navigation, get data in this tutorial  . I try to add this const like below way

**MainComponent**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { Meteor } from 'meteor/meteor';
import { createContainer } from 'meteor/react-meteor-data';
import { Button } from 'react-bootstrap';

import AccountsUIWrapper from './AccountsUIWrapper.jsx';

// App component - represents the whole app
export default class Home extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            hideCompleted: false,
        };
    }

    render() {
        const navbarInstance = (
            <Navbar>
                <Navbar.Header>
                    <Navbar.Brand>
                        <a href="#">React-Bootstrap</a>
                    </Navbar.Brand>
                </Navbar.Header>
                <Nav>
                    <NavItem eventKey={1} href="#">Link</NavItem>
                    <NavItem eventKey={2} href="#">Link</NavItem>
                    <NavDropdown eventKey={3} title="Dropdown" id="basic-nav-dropdown">
                        <MenuItem eventKey={3.1}>Action</MenuItem>
                        <MenuItem eventKey={3.2}>Another action</MenuItem>
                        <MenuItem eventKey={3.3}>Something else here</MenuItem>
                        <MenuItem divider />
                        <MenuItem eventKey={3.4}>Separated link</MenuItem>
                    </NavDropdown>
                </Nav>
            </Navbar>
        );

        return (
            <div>
                {navbarInstance}

                <div className="container">
                    <div className="row">
                        <div className="navbar nav-inline">
                            <AccountsUIWrapper />
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <header>
                        <h1>School Attendance</h1>
                        <h3>Lecturer Report</h3>
                    </header>

                    <h4>This is home</h4>
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

but I got bellow error. and [there](https://github.com/react-bootstrap/react-bootstrap/issues/384) reason as like me.

There add some import

```
import { Button, Navbar, Nav, NavItem, NavDropdown, MenuItem } from 'react-bootstrap';
```

like this then vanish the error, but I got like this

[image]

I want to correct way to Navbar add

Comment: The link that you posted included a solution. Did you try that?

Comment: Could you post the code for your 'Home' component? It would seem that Navbar is undefined, so perhaps there is something incorrect with your imports.

Comment: @JonB this solution for railsJs I want to meteor.

Comment: @FinbarrO'B I want to meteor+react add navigation like  https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components.html#navigation

Comment: You have two questions here: (1) how to get rid of the undefined NavBar and (2) how to properly layout the navigation. You have the answer to (1) already, the real question is (2).

Comment: Ok, I see you have included your imports, and now you get a navbar, but the CSS is not correct. You also need to include the bootstrap CSS links in your page, as it is not packaged with react-bootstrap. See here: https://react-bootstrap.github.io/getting-started.html in the Stylesheets section.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The classes you call in render are not defined.

Where you have import {Button} from 'react-bootstrap' you need to import every component that you plan on using in your file ( that is part of that framework ).

The solution would be adding Navbar, like so:

```
import { Button, Navbar } from 'react-bootstrap'
```

Also have you included Bootstrap styles in your project?
https://react-bootstrap.github.io/getting-started/introduction

Comment: When adding the stylesheets, my whole project seems to shrink as a whole and the Navbar is just out of place. Have you experienced anything like this?

Comment: I just figured out you can't use regular bootstrap with react-bootstrap or you get this weird affect.

Answer (score 0):

firstly install react bootstrap

```
npm install react-bootstrap bootstrap
// or use yarn
yarn add react-bootstrap bootstrap
```

also you need to import Navbar as well you can use this code

```
import Navbar from 'react-bootstrap/Navbar'
// or
import { Navbar } from 'react-bootstrap'
```

for the styling you need to add bootstrap styles. How and which Bootstrap styles you include is up to you, but the simplest way is to include the latest styles from the CDN.

```
<link
  rel="stylesheet"
  href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css"
  integrity="sha384-9aIt2nRpC12Uk9gS9baDl411NQApFmC26EwAOH8WgZl5MYYxFfc+NcPb1dKGj7Sk"
  crossorigin="anonymous"
/>
```